# memcached never expired in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

It's very strange that the session will never expire if I use memcached store even I set
`config.action_controller.session  :session_expires => 1.seconds.from_now`.

And I use extended_fragment_cache to cache fragment, I meet the same problem

```
<% Cache "my_page", {:expires => 1.minutes} do ... %>
```

never expired!

Anyone know where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I change the codes to

ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.seconds

1.minutes} do ... %>

and everything now.